Application Insights - Multi-depth json parsing?
Using parse_json(myJson) only gives me access to the depth 1 fields. So, if I want access to a integer depth 3 field I have to toint(parse_json(tostring(parse_json(tostring(parse_json(myJson)["SubFieldA"]))["SubSubFieldB"]))["SubSubSubFieldC"])
is there a way to simplify this? something like parse_complete_json(myJson)["SubFieldA"]["SubSubFieldB"]["SubSubSubFieldC"]

Yes, actually this should work:
extend Value = toint(parse_json(myJson).SubFieldA.SubFieldB)

But parse_json only works when it is a complete JSON. When there are missing brackets because of size issues, then this is not going to work.
So the json has to be valid and complete.
